# Custom dialog with @HostListener in Angular

Tags: angular, routes, modal-dialog, refresh

I am trying to ask the user, after making unsaved changes and refreshing the page, if he wants to discard these changes and reload the page or cancel the refresh.
I want to use my own dialog instead of the browser's one.
Is that possible with  @HostListener('window:beforeunload')?

Comment: CanDeactivate guard
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57403589/how-do-i-prevent-the-reload-site-alert-angular-8-chrome-75-0

Answer (score 0):

No, `beforeunload` is very limited solution, basically you can only change text in browser window.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload

Comment: Thank you for your reply @kemsky.
Is there any other solution that I can implement ? in all the examples that I had seen, the HostListener decorator was the common solution.

Comment: It is the only universal solution, works even if user manually types address, if you have some links within you application you can create customized directive which will display dialog before changing window.location.

Answer (score 0):

Try CanDeactivate custom dialog

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).