# How do I prevent the "Reload site?" alert? (Angular 8, Chrome 75.0)

Tags: angular, google-chrome

I need to run a piece of code before the user leaves or refreshes the page and only then. Leave is working fine but refresh acts completely differently and doesn't trigger my route guard so instead I'm trying to do it on  `@HostListener("window:beforeunload", ["$event"])`.

Running the code on `unload` doesn't seem to work, I have to do it `beforeunload`.

However the problem is that chrome allows the user to cancel the refresh and then stay after I've already called my code. Then my user has something that I've already told the backend that they don't have anymore.

[image: "Reload site?]

I haven't been able to find any evidence of there being a way to get the value back from this pop-up to know if the user did try to stay.

Instead I've been attempting to try to prevent this popup and that also has me stuck. I've tried every solution I've found on here and none seem to do the trick. What am I missing?

```
    @HostListener("window:beforeunload", ["$event"])
    beforeUnloadHander(event) {
        this.codeINeedToRun();

        //failed attempts to prevent popup =>
        event.preventDefault();
        event.returnValue = null;
        window.onbeforeunload = function () {
            return null;
        };
        event.stopPropagation();
    }
```